# Which one is better "all incurred expenses" or "all expenses incurred?"

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, word-order, writing-style, emphasis

I am writing this document for HR at work and wish to outline what our staff should do to get reimbursed. The sentence should be something along the lines of...

> All incurred expenses/expenses incurred should be claimed within three months of their taking place.

Is there a rule?

Comment: The idiomatic standard for this context is [***all/any expenses incurred***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=all+incurred+expenses+are%2Call+expenses+incurred+are%2Cany+incurred+expenses+are%2Cany+expenses+incurred+are&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=20)

Comment: @fev: But the default sequence for ***proposed cost*** is the opposite of *[any] **expenses incurred***, and that question is in any case closed as a duplicate of an even less relevant question about ***taken pictures***.

Comment: There's a slight difference in meaning or connotation, but either would probably do, unless you have some other type of expenses (e.g. "expenses carried forward"), or want to tell people what to do if expenses aren't incurred.

Comment: I edit procedures like these to insert the word **must**. **Should** will come back to haunt you, as employees will claim they tried and understood they should, but they couldn't get papers under the time limit, so they're late, and so what? It's easy to read *should* as a suggestion, whereas  *must* is a requirement.

Comment: I'd reorder the instruction: Claim all incurred expenses within three months of occurrence. Late submissions are not reimbursed.

Comment: Expenses don't "take place".  Expenses are incurred.  *You must seek reimbursement for expenses within ___ calendar days of incurring them.*

Comment: *All expenses should be claimed within three months of being incurred.*